# Extjs chart : set fields dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

Is it possible to setFields to a chart axes ?

I searched the docs for a `setFields` method but I found none.

I manage to setTitle to an axes but not the field. So I have a `period` variable that holds that field and that changes dynamically on every store update, I tried :

```
chart.axes.get('bottom').Fields = period;
```

It doesn't give any errors but doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with :

```
chart.axes.get('bottom').fields = [period];
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to get a running example.

Anyway.. ExtJS has a configuration based object creation. It means that when you see something like this:

```
 axes: [{
    type: 'Numeric',
    position: 'left',
    fields: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'],
    ...
```

The fields attribute is actually a property of Ext.chart.axis.Numeric class

I would suggest to use the developer tool and inspect the object - you'll learn a lot from that.
And use the [API docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.axis.Numeric)